# How to pass compiler flags with CMake to use GTest

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest

I need help setting up gtest to add additional flags when compiling. Currently, I am getting this warning:

`warning: range-based ‘for’ loops only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11`

My CMakeLists file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6) 

find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(runTests tests.cpp)

target_link_libraries(runTests ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread)\
```

It was created using this tutorial:

- https://www.eriksmistad.no/getting-started-with-google-test-on-ubuntu/

Where should I add the -std=c++11 flag to satisfy this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the feature explicit:

```
target_compile_features(runTests PUBLIC cxx_range_for)
```

Or activating a specific standard (afaik since CMake Version 3.8.2):

```
target_compile_features(runTests PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
```

Complete list of features can be found [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways for you to approach this issue. Side note, are you actually using CMake of version as old as 2.6? Or is it required by your environment to use it for backwards compatibility?

First option:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_CXX_FLAGS "${${PROJECT_NAME}_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${${PROJECT_NAME}_CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

or, if your compiler does not support that, you can use `-std=c++0x` instead.

Additionally, you can use following code to check if your compiler supports one or another:

```
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
```

which would output a boolean value to your `COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11` variable, and then you can further test it and set your flags accordingly.

Second option is to use `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` variable, [as described in documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html). This can be also used as separate property on targets (following [this doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html)):

```
set_property(TARGET tgt PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```